# HighCharts + xAxis label formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm running into this weird and wonderful issue with the xAxis.labels.formatter function within highcharts JS.

I wanted to add a lightbox icon to the xAxis labels of the chart as following:

```
return '<div class="label">'
         +'<a class="lightbox" href="http://www.google.com" data-lightbox="iframe" data-plugin-options=\'{"type":"iframe"}\'>ICON</a>'
       +'</div>';
```

However when rendering this chart the html code shows me the following output:

```
<div class="label">
  <a class="lightbox" href="http://www.google.com" data-lightbox="iframe" data-plugin-options="{"type":"iframe"}">ICON</a>
</div>
```

The problem is with the single quotes being rendered into double quotes

```
data-plugin-options="{"type":"iframe"}"
```

instead of

```
data-plugin-options='{"type":"iframe"}'
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to prevent this from happening.

Things I have tried:

1. use simple escaping with **\'**
2. created a var and passing it into the return string
3. used **.replace(/['"]+/g, '')**

Could someone please point me in the right direction as it's driving me slowly crazy, thanks all

**UPDATE AFTER FEEDBACK**

thank you for your reply, the problem is not the actually single quotes inside of the data-plugin-options attribute but around it, so for example it renders: data-plugin-options=**"**{"type":"iframe"}**"** instead of data-plugin-options=**'**{"type":"iframe"}**'**, I have found out that even if I would add a fake html element e.g  **foo=bar**, it will render this as **foo="bar"**, so it automatically adds the double quotes, within the xAxis label formatter.

Please see my modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6yehxeo/1/) (http://jsfiddle.net/g6yehxeo/1/), and inspect the element of the **icon** label on the xAxis, you will find that it renders with quotes, even while there are none in the original code ? Any idea of how to prevent this, as the lightbox does not seem to work without these.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly escape the string that goes into the `data-plugin-options` attribute. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189067/1869660

```
formatter: function () {
    function escapeAttr(str) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('data-dummy', str);
        return /\"(.*)\"/.exec(div.outerHTML)[1];
    }

    var options = { type: 'iframe'},
        optionsAttr = escapeAttr(JSON.stringify(options));

    return '<div class="label">'
         +   '<a class="lightbox" href="http://www.google.com" data-lightbox="iframe" data-plugin-options="' + optionsAttr + '">ICON</a>'
         + '</div>';
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6yehxeo/

You can also use the built-in [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) method instead of our homemade `escapeAttr()`, but then whoever reads the attribute later needs to [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) the value first to get valid JSON.

Comment: hi Spinxxx, I have tried your solution and updated updated my question with my findings, thank you for your help

Comment: You can't change that behavior - that's how proper HTML is written. If the lightbox doesn't work, add that library to the JSFiddle to investigate further.